# Help needed for finding the script for moving and naming tv folders to tv folders compatible with emby

Tags: command-line, scripts, tv, naming, emby

I need help I don't know how to do it at all.
I have some older tv series which have mostly for each tv episode own folder and for some with the season folder.
I will  list the examples below.
Original folder and files should stay in their original form,
but they should be moved in the series name folder and seasons folder.

```
/home/incoming/TV/Altered.Carbon.S01E05.The.Wrong.Man.1080p.DDP5.1.x264/
/home/incoming/TV/Altered.Carbon.S01E08.1080p.DD5.1.x264/
```

Should create series main folder "Altered Carbon" and subfolder season 01 based on S01 in the name and move folder as it is in the same state

```
/home/incoming/TV/Altered Carbon/Season 01/Altered.Carbon.S01E05.The.Wrong.Man.1080p.DDP5.1.x264/

/home/incoming/TV/Altered Carbon/Season 01/Altered.Carbon.S01E08.1080p.DD5.1.x264/
```

and for season 02 i have all episodes together they should be moved to series name folder with seasons subfolder.

```
/home/incoming/TV/Altered.Carbon.S02.1080p.DDP5.1.x264/
```

Should create series main folder "Altered Carbon" but because S02 it should also add "season 02" subfolder

```
/home/incoming/TV/Altered Carbon/Season 02/Altered.Carbon.S02.1080p.DDP5.1.x264/
```

Same goes for the Black Mirror it should do the same job

```
/Black Mirror S01 1080p DD+ 2.0 x264/
```

Should create series main folder "Black Mirror" but because S02 it should also add "season 01" subfolder

```
/home/incoming/TV/Black Mirror/Season 01//Black Mirror S01 1080p DD+ 2.0 x264/

/Black.Mirror.S02E01.1080p.AMZ.AAC2.0.H.264/
```

Should create series main folder "Black Mirror" but because of S02 it should also add "season 02" subfolder

```
/home/incoming/TV/Black Mirror/Season 02/Black.Mirror.S02E01.1080p.AMZ.AAC2.0.H.264/
```

I remember seeing script on askubuntu but for the last week I tried searching for it, only thing that I can find is ways to do it if you have media files and move them to folders with season.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Does it have a GUI? Can you drag and drop?

Comment: its ubuntu  18.04.6 LTS no gui just cli mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what "emby" is, but in Bash, ...

Something like this:

```
ubuntu@Lenovo:~/TV$ tree
.
├── Altered.Carbon.S01E05.The.Wrong.Man.1080p.DDP5.1.x264
│   ├── file.info
│   ├── file.mp4
│   └── file.srt
├── Altered.Carbon.S01E08.1080p.DD5.1.x264
│   ├── file.info
│   ├── file.mp4
│   └── file.srt
├── Altered.Carbon.S02.1080p.DDP5.1.x264
│   ├── E1
│   │   ├── file.info
│   │   ├── file.mp4
│   │   └── file.srt
│   └── E2
│       ├── file.info
│       ├── file.mp4
│       └── file.srt
├── Black Mirror S01 1080p DD+ 2.0 x264
│   ├── E1
│   │   ├── file.info
│   │   ├── file.mp4
│   │   └── file.srt
│   └── E2
│       ├── file.info
│       ├── file.mp4
│       └── file.srt
└── Black.Mirror.S02E01.1080p.AMZ.AAC2.0.H.264
    ├── file.info
    ├── file.mp4
    └── file.srt

10 directories, 21 files
```

... can be transformed with something like this:

```
ubuntu@Lenovo:~/TV$ for d in */
  do
    d2="${d//./ }"
    t="${d2// S[0-9]*/}"
    s="$(/bin/grep -Po '[ .]S\K[0-9][0-9]' <<<"$d")"
    p="$t/Season $s/"
    mkdir -pv -- "$p"
    mv -nv -- "$d" "$p"
    done
```

... while outputting something like this:

```
mkdir: created directory 'Altered Carbon'
mkdir: created directory 'Altered Carbon/Season 01/'
renamed 'Altered.Carbon.S01E05.The.Wrong.Man.1080p.DDP5.1.x264/' -> 'Altered Carbon/Season 01/Altered.Carbon.S01E05.The.Wrong.Man.1080p.DDP5.1.x264'
renamed 'Altered.Carbon.S01E08.1080p.DD5.1.x264/' -> 'Altered Carbon/Season 01/Altered.Carbon.S01E08.1080p.DD5.1.x264'
mkdir: created directory 'Altered Carbon/Season 02/'
renamed 'Altered.Carbon.S02.1080p.DDP5.1.x264/' -> 'Altered Carbon/Season 02/Altered.Carbon.S02.1080p.DDP5.1.x264'
mkdir: created directory 'Black Mirror'
mkdir: created directory 'Black Mirror/Season 01/'
renamed 'Black Mirror S01 1080p DD+ 2.0 x264/' -> 'Black Mirror/Season 01/Black Mirror S01 1080p DD+ 2.0 x264'
mkdir: created directory 'Black Mirror/Season 02/'
renamed 'Black.Mirror.S02E01.1080p.AMZ.AAC2.0.H.264/' -> 'Black Mirror/Season 02/Black.Mirror.S02E01.1080p.AMZ.AAC2.0.H.264'
```

... into something like this:

```
ubuntu@Lenovo:~/TV$ tree
.
├── Altered Carbon
│   ├── Season 01
│   │   ├── Altered.Carbon.S01E05.The.Wrong.Man.1080p.DDP5.1.x264
│   │   │   ├── file.info
│   │   │   ├── file.mp4
│   │   │   └── file.srt
│   │   └── Altered.Carbon.S01E08.1080p.DD5.1.x264
│   │       ├── file.info
│   │       ├── file.mp4
│   │       └── file.srt
│   └── Season 02
│       └── Altered.Carbon.S02.1080p.DDP5.1.x264
│           ├── E1
│           │   ├── file.info
│           │   ├── file.mp4
│           │   └── file.srt
│           └── E2
│               ├── file.info
│               ├── file.mp4
│               └── file.srt
└── Black Mirror
    ├── Season 01
    │   └── Black Mirror S01 1080p DD+ 2.0 x264
    │       ├── E1
    │       │   ├── file.info
    │       │   ├── file.mp4
    │       │   └── file.srt
    │       └── E2
    │           ├── file.info
    │           ├── file.mp4
    │           └── file.srt
    └── Season 02
        └── Black.Mirror.S02E01.1080p.AMZ.AAC2.0.H.264
            ├── file.info
            ├── file.mp4
            └── file.srt

16 directories, 21 files
```

Comment: Its working like a charm that is the one.